# What is the mathematical notation in the attached figure means?

Tags: distributions, loss-functions, notation, gan

The full context can be found in this link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-generative-adversarial-networks-gans-cd6e4651a29

Appreciate your kind help

[image]

Comment: Without interpreting the context, $\mathbb{I}(\cdot)$ is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)
$$\mathbb{I}{(p_t(x) \geq p_g(x))} = \begin{cases} 1 \quad &\text{if} \quad p_t(x) \geq p_g(x) \\
0 \quad &\text{if} \quad p_t(x) < p_g(x)\end{cases}.$$

Comment: A search for *indicator function* will yield many posts about this, along with several variations on the symbol, such as $\mathbf{I}(.)$ or $\mathbf{1}(.)$

Comment: @microhaus 
Thank you very much

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you very much